# uniform convergence $x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n(x) = x^n.$

$f_n(x)$ converges uniformly on $[0,r]$ for $r<1.$

Proof: Since $r < 1,$ $r^n \rightarrow 0 $ as $n \rightarrow\infty.$ Then, for given $\varepsilon >0 $, we can pick $M\in N$ such that $r^n<\varepsilon$ for all $n\ge M.$ Also, for $x\in[0,r], x\le r$ Then, for $n\ge M, |x^M-0|\le|r^M| = r^M<\varepsilon.$

1. The definition of uniform convergence is $\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists M$ s.t. if $n\ge M, |x^n-0|<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in S.$ But, in my text, it uses $|x^M-0|$ instead of $|x^n-0|.$ Is there any reason for that? Can I use $|x^n-0|?$

While $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly on the above domain, it does not converge uniformly on $[0,1).$

Proof: Suppose $f_n$ converges uniformly. Pick $\varepsilon = 1/2. $ Then, $\exists M$ such that for $n\ge M, |x^n-0| <1/2$ for all $x\in[0,1).$ It implies $x^n<1/2 \rightarrow x<(1/2)^{\frac1n}$, but $\exists x$ such that $(1/2)^{\frac1n}<x<1$. Therefore, it is a contradiction.

2. However, I am wondering why this proof is not applied to the first case. For example, if $r= 0.\overline{9},$ the first case and the second case look the same. Could you elaborate on the difference between the first and the second case?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $0.\overline{9}=1$ and you cannot apply the first case to 1. For your first question, you should use $\vert x^n-0\vert <\varepsilon$. Your text may have a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

High powers of a (positive) number less than $1$ approach $0$.

$0.\bar9=1$, on the other hand (as noted in the comments)...

Comment: Do you mean $x^n \rightarrow 0 $ for all $x \in [0,1)$? If yes, why can't we apply the second case to the proof for the first case?

Comment: We are _fixing_ a number $r\lt1$ at the outset...

Comment: Thus the proof of uniform convergence doesn't break down;  because we can't let $x$ get arbitrarily close to $1$.

Comment: Okay. Then, the second case does not converge uniformly because $x$ can be arbitrarily close to 1? I am wondering why we can't set $r$ arbitrarily close to 1?

Comment: Right.  Given small enough $\epsilon \gt0$, it is possible to get $x^n$ to exceed $\epsilon $, by choosing $x$ closer to $1$...